# Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

My `.bib` files are generated by Mendley desktop and usually contain URLs, ISSN and DOIs, but I don't want those to be displayed in my list of references. How can I get rid of them (short of deleting those from the entries, I just want to not display them...) I am using `biblatex`.

Comment: Mendeley also includes the arXiv entry automatically so to get rid of this use eprint=false Answers question in this duplicate entry
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25179/biblatex-mendeley-remove-obsolete-data-from-bibliography?lq=1

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Assuming you are using standard styles, use `biblatex` package options `doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false`. For example,

```
\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
```

The manual describes these as 'style-specific' options, as they do depend on the bibliography style in use.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and I might ask a new one, but this appears to strip ISBN (useful for books) as well as ISSN (not so useful for journals.

Comment: @ChrisH Would probably be a new question, but I've never seen a published bibliography giving ISBNs (depend on things like hard/soft backing as well as text itself).

Comment: I found another question answering precisely this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/28808 which works for me. I take your point but I'm sure I've seen it in thesis bibliographies, and if you were to cite page numbers it would make sense, as a given numbered edition may not have the same pagination in all versions (considering international versions as well as bindings)

Comment: Where can I find out about the rest of the optional arguments for `biblatex`?

Comment: The standard ones are in the `biblatex` manual, any added by styles should be documented in their manuals.

Answer (score 23):

Alternatively, if you want `biblatex` not to see these fields at all, use Biber and see section 4.5.3 of the `biblatex` manual. You are now able to filter out arbitrary fields (and map them to other fields) before `biblatex` even sees the data with so-called source maps.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=issn, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sarfraz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also very helpful to remove the abstract field, which quite often contains strange characters like % but will rarely ever be used in the bibliography.

Comment: I tried to look it up, but with the current version 2.12 as of *Feb. 2019* there is no section 2.1.1 anymore ([have a look at the biber-manual at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/biber?lang=en)). There is a section 3.1.1 but I couldn't find a clear reference for the given problem there.

Comment: The reference is to a very old version of `biber`. See section 4.5.3 of the current `biblatex` manual.

Comment: could this be used to exclude all fields except a certain selection?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) you can [use the Better-Bibtex plugin to omit specific fields](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/preferences/export/#fields-to-omit-from-export-comma-separated) from its exported bibtex file. This can be configured in Zotero by going to *Preferences->Better Bibtex->Export->Fields->Fields to omit from export*.