# biblatex & Mendeley - remove obsolete data from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references)

I recently started using Mendeley and got very excited about the fact that it searches for all the data about the articles I didn't have before - it gets the URLs, the DOIs, the ISSNs and whatnot. I was only happy until I realised that once I export all this info to a .bib file and compile a paper in .pdf, it gets printed in my bibliographies! I don't need all of my bibliography entries to provide ISSNs and DOIs, but it seems that it is just printed by default.

I'm using BibLaTeX and the authoryear bibliography style, and in the compiled bibliography I get things like:

Stecker, Robert (1990). 'The Boundaries of Art'. In: *The British Journal of Aesthetics* 30.3, pp. 266-272. issn: 0007-0904. doi: 10.1093/bjaesthetics/30.3.266. url: http://bjaesthetics.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/doi/10.1093/bjaesthetics/30.3.266 .

I don't want any of this information, but neither do I want to clear it from my Mendeley database. I tried various bibstyle commands, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/6984 - does the info there solve your problem?

Comment: It all depends on the style your using. Try to change the style, and it will extract other elements from your bibliographic entries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using biber with biblatex (you need biber 0.9.4/biblatex 1.6), you can ignore fields in the bibtex source so that as far as biblatex is concerned, they don't exist in the source at all. See the 0.9.4 biber manual, section 2.1.1