# Getting rid of DOI, ISSN links from bibliography

Tags: bibtex, links, doi

In light of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26318/11134) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31406/11134) AND if I'd want to use `pdflatex` instead of `biblatex`, how do I get rid of doi, ISSN links from my bibliography?

I can write a script such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43773/11134) but that leaves a `,` hanging in each of the entries?

Any comments?

> Edit:
>
> I received very nice input from
>   [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/micohttps://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50960/11134)
>   but I was not able to apply his recommendations (I will do it and post
>   the result here).
>
> Meawhile, here is one not very elegant solution I devised:
>
> I rid my .bib file off all url, doi, issn text like this:
>
> `cat mybibfile.ib | sed -e '/url /d' > mybibfile2.bib`
>
> Then I opened my new .bib file viz, mybibfile2.bib in gedit and
>   replaced all `,\n}` with `}` which ensured that I didn't have a
>   hanging comma(,) in my file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is a bit confusing -- `pdflatex` and `biblatex` are in no way substitutes or otherwise in conflict with each other. Are you maybe looking to use `bibtex` instead of `biblatex`? If so, you should tell us which bibliography style file you intend to use.

Comment: @Mico Oh! I thought `biblatex` was a substitute for `pdflatex`. But I was wondering if there was a way of omitting doi links etc either through `pdflatex` or `bibtex` or the `Jabref` preamble... with the `natbib` bibliography style...

Comment: Natbib is a citation management package, *not* a bibliography style. The package does come with three style files: `plainnat.bst`, `abbrevnat.bst`, and `unsrtnat.bst`. However, one isn't forced to use `natbib` to use one of these style files, and one can use `natbib` with other style files. Thus the question: *Which* style file do you use? It's the style file that contains all formatting instructions that `BibTeX` executes.

Comment: Oh sorry... `unsrtnat`, it is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to make BibTeX ignore fields such as `doi` and `issn` is to set the BibTeX functions that format these fields to a "dummy" instruction that does nothing at all. These functions (and all other BibTeX functions) are contained in the bibliography style file that's in use. Since you indicate that you use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, you could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `unsrtnat.bst` on your TeX system and copy it to, say, `unsrtnatDNA.bst`. (Never edit the original style files.)
- Open the file `unsrtnatDNA.bst` in your favorite text editor. Search for the functions `{format.issn}` and `{format.doi}`. (The headers of these functions are on lines 278 and 292 in my version of the file `unsrtnat.bst`.) Replace their definitions -- the stuff below the respective header lines that's enclosed by a pair of curly braces -- with a "dummy" definition, viz., `{ }`. For instance, you should change the definition of `format.issn` from

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.issn}
  { issn empty$
      { "" }
      { new.block "ISSN " issn * }
  if$
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.issn}
  { }
  ```
- Save and close the file.
- Depending on your TeX distribution, you may have to update the filename database that TeX uses to find all relevant files. For instance, if you use TeXLive, the command that updates the filename database is called `texhash`.
- From now one, use the command `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnatDNA}` in your tex files to instruct BibTeX to use your modified bibliography style file.

Comment: I did what you suggested. But `bibtex` exits with an `exit code 2`. What gives? `:(`

Comment: Heres what I did: Cleared the `.aux` file. Ran `pdflatex` - no error. Ran `bibtex` - Error code 2.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you figure out at which `entry` BibTeX hangs? If so, please post that `entry` in its entirety in an addendum to your question. (You did remember to run `texhash` or its equivalent, right?)

Comment: @DNA: I've discovered a different solution. Please try it out.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out shortly and post the outcome here.

Comment: Hmmm.. I find that the directory where all latex stuff is stored `/usr/share/texmf-texlive` has a read only access. Do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: Not knowing which TeX distribution you have, it's not easy to give a definitive answer to your question. (Could you override the read-only setting using `sudo`?) If you're using the latest version of TeXLive, you could try saving the new `.bst` file in `~/texmf/bibtex/bst`, where `~` stands for your home directory,  `~/texmf` should have been created at the time you set up TeXLive (or when access to TeXLive was set up for you by the sys admin), and `bibtex` and `bst` are subdirectories below `~/texmf` which you may (or may not) have to create.

Comment: I just editted my question with one solution. I'll try and do what you recommended soon! Thanks!

Comment: @DNA: Did you try placing the edited `.bst` file in the same directory as your main `.tex` file? I didn't mention this possibility as it seemed too obvious to even bring up, but maybe that's all you need for now.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try that.

Comment: No.. still an exit code 2

Comment: This is bizarre. I get no error message on my system (MacTeX2011). Why don't you post a complete MWE (minimum working example) that replicates the error you get.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I can! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a elegant solution - but I wrote a quick python script a while back to solve similar problems - in principle can be used to get rid of any fields - and extended easily.

I posted it here.

http://quickscriptfixes.blogspot.com/2013/01/mendeley-bibtex-stripper-in-python.html

Comment: Looks fragile. What happens, e.g., when there is a `=` in some field?

Comment: @mafp - you're of course entirely correct.  

I guess i gave a health warning with the code on the blog. 

However I'm pleased to say it works all the same(unintentionally - or at least untested) - the python statement looks for the 1st = on the line, and treats the rest as raw text.  

That said - there may any number of other ways of tripping it up.  Afraid i didn't do any reading about the .bib standard(?) - just went with what mendeley spat out, and tried to make sense of it.