# Lyx - setting bibtex options

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I want to turn off printing of DOIs in my BibTex bibliography in Lyx.

When I try to add the option **doi=false** under

*Document settings -> Bibliography -> Bibliography generation -> Options*

the bibliography is not generated anymore (i.e. question mark for citation and empty bibliography). How can I set this option via Lyx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, LyX uses BibTeX. And for BibTeX, there is no easy way. You need to do some modifications. The major part is found in [Getting rid of DOI, ISSN links from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/getting-rid-of-doi-issn-links-from-bibliography/50960#50960) (Please, vote up that one!). I rewrote it and added the LyX part.

1. For your bibliography style (e.g. plainnat, alphadin, ...), locate the corresponding `.bst` file. It is likely in your system tex directory under `texmf/bibtex/bst/blabla/`. Copy the file to `texmf/bibtex/bst/blabla/` in your home directory (possibly you have to create the directories). And rename your file `<style>.bst` to something like `<style>-nodoi.bst`. (If you intented to use this style only once you could put it in the same directory as your `.lyx` file is in.)
2. In this file search for the function `format.doi`. Depending on your bibliography style, the entry looks similar to

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.doi}
   { doi empty$
       { "" }
       { doiprefix doi * doiurl doi * make.href }
     if$
   }
   ```

   Change this to

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.doi}
   {
   }
   ```
3. In LyX in the dialog for setting the bibliography style, the new style is not listed at first but after clicking "Rescan" it will show up (except you put the `.bst` file  together with your `.lyx` file; then type the new style name manually).

---

Depending on your bibliography style DOI entries could still keep appearing in your bibliography. Then you have to modify more places in step 2. For example, you should change

```
    FUNCTION { format.doi.urn }
    { urn empty$
         { doi empty$
              { "" }
              { "DOI" doi n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
           if$
         }
         { "URN" urn n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
```

to - maybe

```
    FUNCTION { format.doi.urn }
    { urn empty$
         { "" }
         { "URN" urn n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
```

In LyX, the field "Document settings -> Bibliography -> Bibliography generation -> Options" does not modify the LyX document (actually, the LaTeX document which is internally created by LyX). This setting is used for the internal program call to `bibtex`.

The option `doi=false` is only applicable to biblatex, see
[Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references). But biblatex is not yet fully supported by LyX.