# getting rid of DOI URL etc fields in aipnum4-1.bst

Tags: bibtex, urls, doi

I tried the solution suggested by Mico suggested in [Getting rid of DOI, ISSN links from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/getting-rid-of-doi-issn-links-from-bibliography)

but no luck I get error messages like

```
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry ebbesenNature1998
while executing---line 3454 of file aipnum4-1DNA.bst
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry srituravanicNanolett2004
while executing---line 3454 of file aipnum4-1DNA.bst
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry PrzybillaJOptA2006
while executing---line 3454 of file aipnum4-1DNA.bst
```

and so on
when I replace the format functions in the .bst file by dummy functions like he suggests.

Note also that I prefer for the moment not to use biblatex

Can anybody suggest a way of how to modify the .bst file to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if the file `aipnum4-1.bst` in tex live 2012 is the same one you're using (it has the date 2010-07-25), there doesn't seem to be any explicit `format.doi` function, so it's a matter of figuring out what tag(s) to modify.  it may be as simple as removing the line `doi` from the list under `ENTRY`.  if this isn't enough, then change the `FUNCTION {add.doi}` to have just `{ }` for its definition.  also, in `FUNCTION {init.bib}` there is a line `init.bib.doi`; removing that line might have a useful effect. (not tested.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I think you should make your comments into an answer.

Comment: @Mico -- okay, but with great hesitation, since i can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

**warning:** *not tested!*

this answer is based on the file `aipnum4-1.bst` in tex live 2012, dated 2010-07-25.

there doesn't seem to be any explicit `format.doi` function, so it's a matter of figuring out what tag(s) to modify.

it may be as simple as removing the line `doi` from the list under `ENTRY`.  (the documentation for this item isn't really clear in the manual -- `texdoc btxhak`.)

if this isn't enough, then change the lines

```
FUNCTION {add.doi}
{ }
```

to suppress its activation.

also, in `FUNCTION {init.bib}` there is a line `init.bib.doi`; removing that line might have a useful effect.

Comment: thx for your suggestion. I got that far myself. However that still raised a lot of `pop empty string` errors when running `bibtex`. I finally managed by just commenting out `link.open` and `link.shut` in the `FUNCTION{article}` etc. Apparently `aipnum4-1.bst` always wants to include doi when the items in the bib file contain no crossreference field. Thx for all your help