# Omitting unwanted bibtex information from bibliography

Tags: bibtex

My .bib files are generated by Mendley desktop and usually contain URLs, ISSN and DOIs. I'm using the \usepackage[round]{natbib} package and  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}.

I realize I'm not the first user to ask about this ([question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references); [question2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31406/get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references))--although to be fair this user is asking about a different style than the one I'm using. And like this user, I don't want DOI, URL, ISSN to be displayed in my bibliography. How can I get rid of them?

[Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) suggests [using doi=false](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23118/84732) etc. But I'm unclear how this would be coded. I tried adding doi=false as follows: \bibliographystyle{natbib, doi=false} but this didn't work.

EDIT: Changes for clarity.

Comment: The link you give is about `biblatex`: for `natbib` it will depend on which style you are using. What does your `\bibliographystyle` line say?

Comment: `natbib` is a package for citation management and bibliography formatting. However, there is *no bibliography style* called `natbib`. Moreover, there is no option called `rounded` to pass to the `natbib` package -- did you mean to write `round` instead? Please edit your posting to clarify your setup.

Comment: Made some changes above. I'm using the style plainnat.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example (wath that is is shown in your linked question2).  Add to your question two bib entrys. You can use package `filecontents` to include the bib entrys to your MWE.

Comment: Kurt, I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're asking me to do. Please clarify and I'm happy to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Recommended solution

There's no really simple way to do this elegantly using `natbib`, since the `.bst` files that format the bibliography entries either produce the fields or not. There's no way to selectively turn them on or off. For this reason, I would recommend that instead of using `natbib` you use `biblatex` to manage your bibliography, since this will allow you to have direct control over whether to produce them or not.

See

- [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/2693)

and then the solution in the question that Joseph linked to:

- [Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/2693)

will work.

One minor problem with this solution however, is that there are no `biblatex` styles that mimic `plainnat` exactly, mainly because most Author-Year systems put the year right after the author, and not right at the end like `plainnat` does. If you have any flexibility in choosing a style, you can choose one of the standard `biblatex` `authoryear` styles,  the `apa` style, or the `biblatex-chicago` package with the `authordate` style.  Here's a minimal example using the APA style:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{AD.Smith2001,
  author    = {Arthur D. Smith},
  title     = {A simple model of LaTeX References.},
  journal   = {Journal of LaTeX},
  year      = {2001},
  volume    = {100},
  pages     = {1--10},
  number    = {3},
  keywords  = {LaTeX models; biology},
  doi       = {10.1115/1.1372322},
  publisher = {Cambridge},
  url       = {http://link.aip.org/link/?PBY/321},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa,
            backend=biber,
            natbib=true, % use this to use natbib cite commands
            url=false,
            doi=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\begin{document}
\citet{AD.Smith2001}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Non-recommended (but will work) solution

It's not that difficult to modify a `.bst` file to not print any of these fields.  The `.bst` file `plainnat` has functions that look like this (one for URL, one for ISSN, one for DOI etc.)

```
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISBN " isbn * }
  if$
}
```

We can replace each one of these with a function like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ "" }
```

And this will simply cause any of these fields not to be printed.  Make a copy of `plainnat.bst`, give it a new name, (I've called it `plainnat-noURL`, and save it in the same folder as your `.tex` document. Then edit the file and for each of functions, replace that function with one like the one above.

With this minimal example  we get the output we want.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{AD.Smith2001,
  author    = {Arthur D. Smith},
  title     = {A simple model of LaTeX References.},
  journal   = {Journal of LaTeX},
  year      = {2001},
  volume    = {100},
  pages     = {1--10},
  number    = {3},
  keywords  = {LaTeX models; biology},
  doi       = {10.1115/1.1372322},
  publisher = {Cambridge},
  url       = {http://link.aip.org/link/?PBY/321},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\begin{document}
\cite{AD.Smith2001}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat-noURL}
\bibliography{\jobname}   % using the bib file created with filecontents
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]