# How to unset a toggle in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/2975)

The standard.bbx file sets toggles for doi,url and eprint that are being checked later by the doi+eprint+url macro.

My goal is to have doi printed, but not url. IIUC, I actually don't need to redefine the macro (although I could), but just need to set the url toggle to false. Unfortunately, the biblatex manual even does not mention the word 'toggle' so I don't know how to set the url option to false.

I tried simply

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{url}{false}
```

but that just renders an error about conflicting options.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: *doh* yeah, that was it. Somehow it didn't click for me that the package options are actually those. Thanks. wanna make an answer for this? Don't think it's a duplicate, as it's much simpler than those answers there.