# LaTeX template for Journal of Computational Biology

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, citing

I am using lyx and have to insert citation by following rules. I could not find any specific citation style in lyx.

References should be presented in the following style:

Journal Paper: Fujar, B.R., Smith, R.N., Jackson, T.R., et al. 1996. Navigating  gopherspace  with  neural  implants.  J.  Neurol. 10, 275–280.

Book: Hillis, D.M., and Moritz, C. 1991. Molecular Systematics. Sinaur Associates, Sunderland, MA.

Chapter within Edited Book: Knight, J.R., and Myers, E.W. 1992. Approximate regular expression pattern matching with concave gap penalties, 66-76. In Chrochemore, M., and Galil, Z., eds. Combinatorial Pattern Matching. Springer-Verlag, New York.

Citation of references in the text:
  References in the text should be cited by author names and publication year. When a text citation includes one or two authors, list all authors and the publication year, e.g., Smith (2008) or Smith and Jones (2008), but for text citations for three or more authors, cite the first author only followed by et al. and the publication year, e.g., Smith et al. (2008).

Comment: You should use `biblatex` and its optional `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames`. You can set `style=authoryear`(or one of its variants). How to use biblatex with Lyx is explained here: http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex.

Comment: after installing biblatex and updating with texhash error occurred saying: biblatex missing. style option is showing the biblatex.

Comment: Did you try to compile from within a "classic" tex editor, or even from the command line?

Comment: i am using lyx 2.02

Comment: The problem is that I never used lyx and can help mainly on the tex side. Did you install biblatex from within lyx?

Comment: thanks for the help. But i have tried the style kluwer and it seems to be working fine. Now i only have to remove article urls from bibliography.

Comment: I have created a .bst file with the help of latex makebib. which can be accessed by : https://github.com/taushifkhan/DocMaker/blob/master/takh_JCB.bst

Comment: To remove the URLs, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references