# Biblatex Options do not work, bibliography is not customizable

Tags: biblatex

I am working on my thesis at the moment and I have the following problem:

I want to customize the bibliography so that the surname is shown first (and the first name is shortened), ISBN and DOI should be left out.

I read the following article: [Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references). So according to this I applied the suggested customizations, but it seems that none of them work for my document.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,                         
               12pt,                            
               oneside,                         
               toc=listof,                     
               listof=entryprefix,              
               headings=normal                  
               ]{scrreprt}                 

  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                   
  \usepackage{blindtext}

 \usepackage[backend=biber,                      
             bibencoding=utf8,                      
             style=alphabetic,                  
             doi=false,                         
             isbn=false,
             dashed=false,                          
             uniquename=false,                  
             ]{biblatex}                            
 \addbibresource{bib/literatur.bib}     

 \begin{document}

 \blindtext \cite{Black.1973}

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

And here is my bib-file:

```
% This file was created with Citavi 5.5.0.1

@article{Black.1973,
 author = {Black, Fischer and Scholes, Myron},
 year = {1973},
 title = {The Pricing of Options and Corporate Liabilities},
 pages = {637--654},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {81},
 number = {3},
 issn = {0022-3808},
 journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
 doi = {10.1086/260062}
}
```

And here are screenshots of the result I'm getting:

[image: Text]
[image: bibliography]

Here is the code from my `.blg` file:

```
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[0] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[43] biber-MSWIN32:303> INFO - === 
[79] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[184] Biber.pm:835> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[200] Biber.pm:3670> INFO - Processing section 0
[222] Biber.pm:3840> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'bib/literatur.bib' for section 0
[230] bibtex.pm:1435> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[239] bibtex.pm:1292> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bib/literatur.bib'
[247] Utils.pm:164> WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\FSCHAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tksrf7X3UK\literatur.bib_10088.utf8, line 3, warning: 45 characters of junk seen at toplevel
[258] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[258] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[258] Biber.pm:3499> INFO - Sorting list 'anyt/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'anyt' and locale 'de-DE'
[259] Biber.pm:3505> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[261] bbl.pm:608> INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[261] bbl.pm:712> INFO - Output to test.bbl
[262] Biber.pm:109> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63649/discussion-on-question-by-felixws-biblatex-options-do-not-work-bibliography-is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alphabetic` style does not know the option `dashed`, so calling that option will cause an error. So we will have to drop that option.

`uniquename=false,` does not make sense with the style you use here.

With `giveninits=true` you can get initials of first names.

So you will want to use `biblatex` with

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, doi=false, isbn=false, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
```

Finally you want

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{edi‌​tor}{family-given}
\D‌​eclareNameAlias{tran‌​slator}{family-given‌​}
```