# Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in individual call to \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

This question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references).
The accepted answer to that question is to pass a global parameter to the `biblatex` package.

What I don't see is, what needs to be done to call `\printbibliography` with different options? Say, one bibliography is printed with `doi` information and the next one without.

So, how to change package options within the `document` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can not set `biblatex`'s global options locally within your document. Some options can be set on a per-type or per-entry basis (starting with version 3.13 of `biblatex` many more options are settable at those scopes: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/866, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/877), but that is not the same as toggling one option inside the document. Note that some option values are passed on to the backend and thus can not be changed on the fly since they need to be fixed throughout the entire document.

The internal implementation of the options for DOI, ISBN, `eprint`, however, can be easily changed locally. The options are implemented via an `etoolbox` toggle (see [`standard.bbx`, ll. 4-21](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/c71ee542a3301b7a1e8bfc4420f581a2207ffa13/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L4-L21)). Calling the option `doi`, `isbn`, `eprint`, `url` or `related` as `<option>=<value>` is pretty much equivalent to setting a toggle of the name `bbx:<option>` to `<value>`.

Hence, you can try something like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography[title=\refname\ with DOI]

\begingroup
\togglefalse{bbx:doi}
\printbibliography[title=\refname\ without DOI]
\endgroup

\printbibliography[title=\refname\ with DOI again]
\end{document}
```

[image: Three bibliographies with the same entry: The first and third have a DOI, the second does not show it.]

---

Note that this is a viable solution if you want to locally (regionally) disable certain features in your document. If you want to suppress the DOI for certain entries, for entries with a certain property (for example for entries of a certain type), then there are more natural ways to do that (for example with a per-type option, a sourcemap or a test).

Comment: This works great, thank you!